# How to Bind ItemsSource of ListBox which is a Child of ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say I have a View/Page something like below:

```
Category1     Category2     .........     Category(n)

Tile1         Tile1                       Tile1
Tile2         Tile2                       Tile2
.....         .....                       .....
.....         .....                       .....
Tile(n)       Tile(n)                     Tile(n)
```

The XAML used to Create the above OutPut:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}" >

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="500">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" />

                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lst"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ??????}" >

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=lst, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataContext.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Converter={StaticResource stringToBrushConverter}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DataContext.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Converter ={StaticResource stringToBrushConverter}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="125" Width="250">
                                <Path Data="{Binding DataContext.ImageData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                      Width="68" Height="68" Margin="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource spaceToNewLineConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           Margin="40,10,10,10" FontSize="24" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But the problem is that **I don't know the binding of ItemsSource of the ListBox.** So, I don't get the Output as shown above.

Here is how my database tables look like:

[image]

Comment: show definition of `MenuCategories` property..

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Design_Master_Category> _menuCategories;
        public ObservableCollection<Design_Master_Category> MenuCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return _menuCategories;
            }
            set
            {
                _menuCategories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MenuCategories")
            }

Comment: does `Design_Master_Category` have property that contain collection of `Design_Master_TileItems`? if yes, you can bind ListBox's `ItemsSource` to that property

Comment: No, I get only empty Listboxes.

Comment: and if you inspect that property at run-time (debug->breakpoint), is it actually empty? if yes, then the problem is not at binding part

Comment: I have tried that : Here is the declaration of that property public virtual ICollection<Design_Master_TileItems> Design_Master_TileItems { get; set; } I can't put a breakpoint on that but in constructor of that class it's new instance is created where I kept a breakpoint and I show that count always remains zero. But table in my database contains some data. I don't know what the problem is and also note that this class is auto-generated by ef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind to `Design_Master_Category` that store collection of `Design_Master_TileItems`, for example :

```
......
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lst"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Design_Master_TileItems} >
 ......
```

If you find that the property is empty at run-time as stated in comment, it means the problem is not at your binding. You need to fix your query. I am by no means well-experienced with EF, but here is my suggestion :

> try to use `.Include(o => o.Design_Master_TileItems)` function when querying `Design_Master_Category` table. [[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)]